# Does PyQt5 have a transition effect like Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, kivy

Kivy Gui have a transition animation to switch between windows (going back and forth also) we can do it easily in kivy. But in PyQt5 I did't find out any way to transit between window (with animation) and going back and forth to a window again and again is also not working. So, is there any way to do like Kivy do transitions, going back and forth to a window easily in PyQt5.

Answer (score 1):

Qt doesn't provide a similar effect on its own, but it still can be achieved using a subclass of a [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) (which behaves similarly to a QTabWidget, but without any QTabBar).

In the following example I'll show you how to implement a basic "swap" transition between two widgets that are added to a QStackedWidget, the next widget will scroll from right to left if the index is greater than the current, and vice versa.

```
class TransitionWidget(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):
    _nextIndex = _nextWidget = None
    _orientation = QtCore.Qt.Horizontal

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            startValue=0., endValue=1., duration=250)
        self._animation.valueChanged.connect(self._aniUpdate)
        self._animation.finished.connect(self._aniFinished)
        self._animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)

    def setDuration(self, duration):
        self._animation.setDuration(duration)

    def setCurve(self, curve):
        if isinstance(curve, QtCore.QEasingCurve):
            self._animation.setEasingCurve(curve)

    def setOrientation(self, orientation):
        self._orientation = orientation

    def getRange(self, prevIndex, nextIndex):
        rect = self.rect()
        currentStart = nextEnd = QtCore.QPoint()
        if self._orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            if prevIndex < nextIndex:
                currentEnd = QtCore.QPoint(-rect.width(), 0)
                nextStart = QtCore.QPoint(rect.width(), 0)
            else:
                currentEnd = QtCore.QPoint(rect.width(), 0)
                nextStart = QtCore.QPoint(-rect.width(), 0)
        else:
            if prevIndex < nextIndex:
                currentEnd = QtCore.QPoint(0, -rect.width())
                nextStart = QtCore.QPoint(0, rect.width())
            else:
                currentEnd = QtCore.QPoint(0, rect.width())
                nextStart = QtCore.QPoint(0, -rect.width())
        return currentStart, currentEnd, nextStart, nextEnd

    def setCurrentIndex(self, index):
        if index == self.currentIndex():
            return
        # prepare the next widget changes
        if self._nextWidget is not None:
            self._nextWidget.hide()
        self._nextIndex = index
        self._nextWidget = self.widget(index)
        self._nextWidget.show()
        rect = self.rect()
        rect.translate(self.rect().topRight())
        self._nextWidget.setGeometry(rect)
        self._nextWidget.raise_()
        self._animation.start()

    def _aniFinished(self):
        super().setCurrentIndex(self._nextIndex)
        self._nextIndex = self._nextWidget = None

    def _aniUpdate(self, value):
        if not self._animation.state():
            return
        currentStart, currentEnd, nextStart, nextEnd = self.getRange(self.currentIndex(), self._nextIndex)
        rect = self.rect()
        self.currentWidget().setGeometry(rect.translated(QtCore.QLineF(currentStart, currentEnd).pointAt(value).toPoint()))
        self._nextWidget.setGeometry(rect.translated(QtCore.QLineF(nextStart, nextEnd).pointAt(value).toPoint()))
        self.update()
```

Example code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    mainLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(mainWidget)
    transitionWidget = TransitionWidget()
    mainLayout.addWidget(transitionWidget)
    pageCount = 10
    for page in range(pageCount):
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(widget)
        pageLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Page {}'.format(page + 1))
        layout.addWidget(pageLabel, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        prevBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Previous')
        if not page:
            prevBtn.setEnabled(False)
        layout.addWidget(prevBtn)
        nextBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Next')
        layout.addWidget(nextBtn)
        if page == pageCount - 1:
            nextBtn.setEnabled(False)
        transitionWidget.addWidget(widget)
        prevBtn.clicked.connect(lambda _, page=page: transitionWidget.setCurrentIndex(page - 1))
        nextBtn.clicked.connect(lambda _, page=page: transitionWidget.setCurrentIndex(page + 1))

    sep = QtWidgets.QFrame(frameShape=QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
    mainLayout.addWidget(sep)
    orientationCombo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    orientationLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
    mainLayout.addLayout(orientationLayout)
    orientationCombo.addItems(['Horizontal', 'Vertical'])
    orientationCombo.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda o: transitionWidget.setOrientation(o + 1))
    orientationLayout.addRow('Orientation', orientationCombo)
    durationSpin = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(minimum=50, maximum=1000, singleStep=50, suffix='ms')
    orientationLayout.addRow('Duration', durationSpin)
    durationSpin.setValue(transitionWidget._animation.duration())
    durationSpin.valueChanged.connect(transitionWidget.setDuration)
    mainWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```